# adapter getCount and listView getChildCount are not equal

Tags: android, testing

I'm trying to set some tests for my android app, and I'm testing that the creation of an entry in the database is displayed in my ListView.

here is some code snippet:

```
mDbHelper.createAccount();
assertEquals(1, mAccountListAdapter.getCount());
assertEquals(1, mAccountList.getChildCount());
```

the first assert works fine
but in the second, getChildCount return 0.

So the adapter is good, but the listView does not display it?

When I test it manually, the feature works though.

Comment: My uneducated guess would be that mAccountList is not populated yet once you call getChildCount(). Also I'm not exactly sure if I recommended to rely on ListView.getChildCount() as it might contain child Views not related to your Adapter provided ones.

Answer (score 2):

`mAccountList.getChildCount()` refers to the `ViewGroup`'s method that returns the number of the views that this view contains, it's not `ListView`'s method itself. So your assertion is invalid.

Comment: I know that, but I can't find any other method that gives me the number of displayed views in ListView, I guess I'll go with getFirstVisiblePosition()

Comment: You could add `OnScrollListener` to the `ListView`. It's method `onScroll` contains `visibleItemCount` argument. AFAIK, `onScroll` will be invoked even if the list is too small to scroll (or even it has no rows at all).

Answer (score 2):

The getCount() method returns the number of items contained in the list 
The getChildCount() method returns the number of items visible in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**getCount()** returns you a count of items in Adapter (total in list), **getChildCount()** is a ViewGroup method that returns you number of subviews. ListView actively reuses views so if your list has *1000* items **getCount()** will return *1000*, **getChildCount()** - *around 10 or so*...